# "(190) Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token" when swhitching to Facebook c# sdk 5.0.8

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

After moving from v4 to v5.0.3, i'm switching to Facebook C# SDK v5.0.8 Beta

With the v5.03, i had:

```
                CanvasAuthorizer auth;
                var fb = new FacebookClient(appId, appSecret);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_requiredAppPermissions))
                {
                    auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = _requiredAppPermissions.Split(',') };
                }
                else
                {
                    auth = new CanvasAuthorizer();// { Permissions = RWE.Core.Config.FacebookPerms };
                }
                if (_AuthUrlCancel != "") auth.CancelUrlPath = _AuthUrlCancel;
                if (_AuthUrlReturn != "") auth.ReturnUrlPath = _AuthUrlReturn;

                if (auth.Authorize())
                {
                    fb = new FacebookClient(this.CurrentSession.AccessToken);
                    //do what i want
                }
```

Now, with the v5.0.8, it's not working and tells me :

> (190) Invalid OAuth 2.0 Access Token
>     at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Type resultType)
>     at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient.Api(String path, IDictionary`2 parameters, HttpMethod httpMethod, Type resultType)
>     at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.HasPermissions(String appId, String appSecret, Int64 userId, String[] permissions)
>     at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebContext.IsAuthorized(String[] permissions)
>     at Facebook.Web.FacebookWebAuthorizer.Authorize()

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the confusion. FacebookClient is not a direct substitution for FacebookApp. FacebookApp used to look at the session and get the access_token. FacebookClient does not do that.

I would suggest taking a look at [this](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation) tutorial and you will find out the appropriate way to do this. But in short you need to do this:

```
var accessToken = FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken;
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
```

or use FacebookWebClient like:

```
var client = new FacebookWebClient();
```

FacebookWebClient will handle getting the access token from the session for you. FacebookClient will not.

Comment: Thank you Nathan but I still get a problem when using Permissions. If no Permissions are defined, it's great.

        var accessToken = FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken;
        var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

        var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(FacebookWebContext.Current);
        //auth.Permissions = new[] {"email"}; //THIS IS NOT WORKING
        if (auth.Authorize())
        {
            dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("me");
            lblTest.Text = myInfo.name;
        }
//Same pb with FacebookWebAuthorizer